# Prove that f(x,y) is not continuous for any a element of R

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, functions, continuity

Given function 
$$ f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
          3xy/(x^2 + y^2) & (x,y) \neq (0,0) \\
                                a  & (x,y) = (0,0)
\end{cases}$$
prove there exists no $a \in \Bbb R$ such that f is continuous at (x,y) = (0,0).

This is just an example question. I have a test coming up and dont know how to prove questions like these.
Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Hint: find sequences $(x_n,y_n)$ and $(x_n',y_n')$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (x_n,y_n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n',y_n')=0$ but $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(x_n,y_n)\ne\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n',y_n')$.

Comment: As @Math1000 says. Often it is sufficient to go along different lines. So, in this example, approach $(0,0)$ along 1) the line $y=0$ and 2) the line $y=x$. If you get different limits, the function $f$ cannot be continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: thanks, is that enough for an exam question do you think??

Comment: Yeah, that's the kind of argument I would look for (and I used to grade for a real analysis course).

Comment: thats great, thank you !

Answer (score 5):

In order for the function to be continuous at $(x,y) = (0,0)$, the limit must exist at that point and be equal to $a$.  The question asks you to prove that there is no value $a$ such that $$ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{3xy}{x^2 + y^2} = a $$

For this limit to exist, it must be the same when approaching $(0,0)$ from all paths.  If we try the path $y = x$, we get the value of $\frac{3}{2}$.  If we try the path $y = 2x$, we get the value of $\frac{6}{5}$.  This means that the limit does not exist, and thus no value of $a$ will make the function continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: thanks very much! and would that approach be sufficient for an exam question do you think??

Comment: Absolutely.  In order to show that the limit doesn't exists, you only need to find two paths that yield different values.

Comment: great thanks !!